# missing_compare error from "finalfit" package

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to get this command 'missing_compare' from the 'finalfit' package to work for my dataset:

```
proced<- c(1,NA,0,1,0,1,0)
asa<- c(4,3,4,2,5,1,NA)
albumin<- c(NA, NA, 3.572, NA, NA, NA, 4.262)
death<- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0)
bmi<- c(26.04, NA, 31.23, 36.93, 28.9, NA, 30.01)
dataframe = data.frame(proced, as, albumin, death, bmi)
```

(This data frame is actually a lot bigger)

Then:

```
  dataframe$death = factor(dataframe$death)
  dataframe$proced = factor(dataframe$proced)
  dataframe$asa = factor(dataframe$asa)
```

And then:

```
explanatory = c("proced", "asa", 
                "bmi", "albumin")
dependent = "death"


dataframe %>% 
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory, 
                     na_include=TRUE, p=TRUE)
```

But I can't get this to work:

```
 dataframe %>% 
  missing_compare(dependent, explanatory)
```

I get this error when I try to do the missing_compare command with my entire dataset:

```
Error in `[.default`(x, , 2) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In cor(x, rank(y)) : the standard deviation is zero
2: In cor(x, rank(y)) : the standard deviation is zero
```

Help!

Comment: Can you use SO [edit] facilities to fix the code that produces an error at the step where `dataframe` is assigned? `Error in data.frame(proced, as, albumin, death, bmi) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 0`

Answer (score 1):

Your dependent variable `death` has no missing values, which is the point of using the `missing_compare` function. Check out the documentation for that function for more info, <strike>though it is pretty sparse</strike>.

The `missing_compare` function compares an explanatory variable when the dependent variable is missing to the explanatory variable when the dependent variable is not missing. It applies tests to analyze whether these 2 are from the same distribution.

Using your example to illustrate this (note I reduce the number of DV's for simplicity):

```
explanatory = c("proced", "bmi")
dependent = "death"

dataframe2 <- dataframe
dataframe2$death[3:4] = NA

dataframe2 %>% 
  missing_compare(dependent, explanatory)

Missing data analysis: death           Not missing  Missing     p
2                       proced         0    2 (66.7) 1 (33.3) 1.000
3                                      1    2 (66.7) 1 (33.3)      
1                          bmi Mean (SD)    28.3 (2) 34.1 (4) 0.058
Warning message:
In chisq.test(tab, correct = FALSE) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

I added 2 `NA` values to the dependent variable `death`, and the code runs. So for example the function is comparing the `bmi` values when `death` is missing to the values when it is not. The `p` column indicates whether the difference between the groups is statistically significant (Chi-Squared and Kruskal-Wallis for the continuous vars). I'd caution against relying solely on a p-value for this type of analysis, but that is irrelevant to how the code works.

And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Edit: great vignette

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @astrofunkswag, the purpose of this function is to compare the distribution of missingness across a particular variable.

You would be better starting with a visualisation of your missing data e.g.

`dataframe %>%
  missing_pairs(dependent, explanatory)`

That will help you understand what data you have.

One sweats away at extensive vignettes and people accuse you of sparse documentation :)
http://finalfit.org/articles/missing.html

Let me know if you still can't get it to work.